# enqueue_style is not working

Tags: theme-development, css, wp-enqueue-style

I try to load the main stylesheet with enqueue_style - but it isn't working.
Here is my code from functions.php:

```
function my_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
      }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Loading the stylesheet in the header.php by using a link-tag works fine.
I can't find the error - it seems that code is ignored - but function.php is loading.

I also tried to use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Because it is the recommended way to link to styles and scripts I want to get this work. I also want to use enqueue_scripts for some js and jQuery scripts.

Thanks for any hint or advice

The solution: I forgot to call wp_head() in the header.php - added and everything works :-)

Comment: Do you see Errors (404) in your developer tool bar?

Comment: there are no errors in the developer tool bar, is there a special point to check? I have the wp developer plugins installed, wp_debug is true.

Comment: I meant your browsers dev toolbar (F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I) and your Network or Console tab...

Comment: ok, no there are no 404 errors - load of the page is 200, pictures are 304.

Comment: Please look at your scripts. Go to your Elements/DOM tab and locate your script: Is it there? Is in the Network tab? Can you see it under Resources > Frames > Scripts?

Comment: thanks a lot kaiser - at the moment I try to link the main stylesheet to the site by using enqueue_style. This is not loaded, there is no css in the browser. it seems that wp doesn't take care about the function, nothing happened. If there is an error in the functions.php the executions stops, I checked this. So there is no stop at the moment, I wonder why the stylesheet isn't loaded?

Comment: Ok, I guess there won't be a solution to this [until you learn how to use the dev tools](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI). This question is lacking too much needed information and you'll need to be able to provide it.

Comment: thank you - I think we have a misunderstanding. I see no opportunity to check a css file, which is not loaded from the php at the server side. I really appreciate your help and the link, get some new console hints. That will help me with my next task to get the js working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution: I forgot to call wp_head() in the header.php - added and everything works :-)

Answer (score 1):

`get_template_directory_uri()` has **no** trailing slash.

From [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri):

> Note: Does not return a trailing slash following the directory
>   address.

Use `get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css'` and it will works (it should...).

Comment: thanks - I deleted the slash by testing around - added it again, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: @Guido to avoid someone give again and again my answer, you should edit the question adding the trailing slash if does not work. That aside, have you read **kaiser** comment?

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to bellow:

```
 function my_scripts() {
          wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
          }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Note: `get_template_directory_uri()` has no trailing slash(/).

Whenever you have error related to css or js file loading first check in developer tools like firebug whether the link or script tags for css or js respectively loaded or not if loaded then get the url from there and execute in browser if coding coming then ok or else correct the path then change the same in code accordingly.

Comment: thanks - I tested already - it doesn't work with or without leading slash. directory is done, file is there, but it's not loadings the style.css

Comment: can you execute the file url in browser and let here know what you are getting. Like 404 or 403

Comment: executing the file url in the browser shows the correct style.css file. If I call the style.css within the header.php file (with a link tag) it works. Just doing it by wp_enqueue_style ends up with no css - I really wonder why. The file is there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment. This may work Try script for style too. Like this

```
function my_scripts() {
          wp_enqueue_script( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
          }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

or
try

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```

Comment: thanks - it is not working that way. I also checked the slash and corrected in the orig. posting.